# javax.el.ELException: Provider com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found

Tags: java, tomcat

Despite a lot of problem solutions I have stuck on the problem with `ELException`:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/tiles-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.el.ELException: Provider com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactorygetObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Provider com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found
        at javax.el.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:101)
        at javax.el.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:197)
        at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:197)
        at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:168)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl.<init>(JspApplicationContextImpl.java:46)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspApplicationContextImpl.getInstance(JspApplicationContextImpl.java:76)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.getJspApplicationContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:217)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$TilesElActivator.createEvaluator(TilesConfigurer.java:407)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesContainerFactory.createAttributeEvaluatorFactory(TilesConfigurer.java:374)
        at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createContainer(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesContainerFactory.createContainer(TilesConfigurer.java:296)
        at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainer(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:114)
        at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.initialize(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:64)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer.afterPropertiesSet(TilesConfigurer.java:270)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
        at javax.el.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:87)
        ... 40 more
```

I'm sure that it isn't due to any user impact in web application code since another server with the same application is running well and both app's code is identical. Both servers` environments looks identical as well.

I'm using `Apache Tomcat/8.0.37` and `oracle-java8-jdk-amd64`.

Below is the list of `WEB-INF\lib` used libraries:

```
activation-1.1.jar               hibernate-c3p0-4.2.7.Final.jar                  lucene-analyzers-3.6.2.jar        slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar                    tiles-autotag-core-runtime-1.1.0.jar
amqp-client-3.3.4.jar            hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar   lucene-core-3.6.2.jar             snakeyaml-1.11.jar                        tiles-compat-3.0.3.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar                  hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar                  lucene-facet-3.6.2.jar            solr-analysis-extras-3.6.2.jar            tiles-core-3.0.3.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar              hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.7.Final.jar         lucene-grouping-3.6.2.jar         solr-core-3.6.2.jar                       tiles-el-3.0.3.jar
asm-4.2.jar                      hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar           lucene-highlighter-3.6.2.jar      solr-solrj-3.6.2.jar                      tiles-extras-3.0.3.jar
avro-1.7.5.jar                   hibernate-search-4.4.0.Final.jar                lucene-kuromoji-3.6.2.jar         spring-amqp-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar             tiles-freemarker-3.0.3.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar                 hibernate-search-analyzers-4.4.0.Final.jar      lucene-memory-3.6.2.jar           spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar              tiles-jsp-3.0.3.jar
c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar                 hibernate-search-engine-4.4.0.Final.jar         lucene-misc-3.6.2.jar             spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar            tiles-mvel-3.0.3.jar
cas-client-core-3.1.12.jar       hibernate-search-orm-4.4.0.Final.jar            lucene-phonetic-3.6.2.jar         spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar          tiles-ognl-3.0.3.jar
cassandra-driver-core-2.1.2.jar  hibernate-validator-5.1.0.Final.jar             lucene-smartcn-3.6.2.jar          spring-context-support-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar  tiles-request-api-1.0.3.jar
cassandra-driver-dse-2.1.2.jar   httpclient-4.3.3.jar                            lucene-spatial-3.6.2.jar          spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar             tiles-request-freemarker-1.0.3.jar
cglib-3.1.jar                    httpcore-4.3.2.jar                              lucene-spellchecker-3.6.2.jar     spring-cql-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar              tiles-request-jsp-1.0.3.jar
classmate-1.0.0.jar              jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar                      lucene-stempel-3.6.2.jar          spring-data-cassandra-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar   tiles-request-mustache-1.0.3.jar
commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar      jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.12.jar                   lz4-1.2.0.jar                     spring-data-commons-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar     tiles-request-servlet-1.0.3.jar
commons-codec-1.6.jar            javaee-api-7.0.jar                              mail-1.4.7.jar                    spring-expression-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar       tiles-request-servlet-wildcard-1.0.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar    javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar                         mchange-commons-java-0.2.3.4.jar  spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar             tiles-request-velocity-1.0.3.jar
commons-compress-1.4.1.jar       javassist-3.7.ga.jar                            metrics-core-3.0.2.jar            spring-jms-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar              tiles-servlet-3.0.3.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4.jar             javax.mail-1.5.0.jar                            mvel2-2.0.11.jar                  spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar              tiles-template-3.0.3.jar
commons-digester-2.0.jar         jawr-3.3.3.jar                                  netty-3.9.0.Final.jar             spring-rabbit-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar           tiles-velocity-3.0.3.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar               jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar                      ognl-2.7.3.jar                    spring-retry-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar            validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar             jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar  oro-2.0.8.jar                     spring-security-cas-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar     velocity-1.6.2.jar
commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar          jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar                       paranamer-2.3.jar                 spring-security-config-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar  velocity-tools-2.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar        jna-4.0.0.jar                                   poi-3.10-FINAL.jar                spring-security-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar    waffle-jna-1.7.jar
commons-pool-1.5.4.jar           jna-platform-4.1.0.jar                          poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL.jar          spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar     
compiler-0.8.4.jar               jstl-1.2.jar                                    poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-FINAL.jar  spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar               xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar                  liquibase-core-3.1.1.jar                        postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc41.jar    spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
ehcache-2.8.3.jar                log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar                      quartz-2.2.1.jar                  spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar
freemarker-2.3.20.jar            logback-classic-1.1.3.jar                          stax-api-1.0.1.jar
guava-16.0.jar                   logback-core-1.1.3.jar                          slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar               tiles-api-3.0.3.jar
```

Below is the list of `/usr/share/java` libraries which are used by Tomcat8:

```
commons-dbcp-1.4.jar    jsp-api-2.3.jar                     tomcat8-catalina.jar                     tomcat8-i18n-fr-8.0.37.jar    tomcat8-jni.jar                 tomcat8-util-scan-8.0.37.jar
commons-dbcp.jar        libintl.jar                         tomcat8-catalina-storeconfig-8.0.37.jar  tomcat8-i18n-fr.jar           tomcat8-jsp-api-8.0.37.jar      tomcat8-util-scan.jar
commons-pool-1.6.jar    tomcat8-annotations-api-8.0.37.jar  tomcat8-catalina-storeconfig.jar         tomcat8-i18n-ja-8.0.37.jar    tomcat8-jsp-api.jar             tomcat8-websocket-8.0.37.jar
commons-pool.jar        tomcat8-annotations-api.jar         tomcat8-coyote-8.0.37.jar                tomcat8-i18n-ja.jar           tomcat8-juli-8.0.37.jar         tomcat8-websocket-api-8.0.37.jar
ecj.jar                 tomcat8-api-8.0.37.jar              tomcat8-coyote.jar                       tomcat8-jasper-8.0.37.jar     tomcat8-juli.jar                tomcat8-websocket-api.jar
eclipse-ecj-3.11.0.jar  tomcat8-api.jar                     tomcat8-dbcp-8.0.37.jar                  tomcat8-jasper-el-8.0.37.jar  tomcat8-servlet-api-8.0.37.jar  tomcat8-websocket.jar
eclipse-ecj.jar         tomcat8-catalina-8.0.37.jar         tomcat8-dbcp.jar                         tomcat8-jasper-el.jar         tomcat8-servlet-api.jar
el-api-3.0.jar          tomcat8-catalina-ant-8.0.37.jar     tomcat8-el-api-8.0.37.jar                tomcat8-jasper.jar            tomcat8-tribes-8.0.37.jar
el-impl-2.2.jar         tomcat8-catalina-ant.jar            tomcat8-el-api.jar                       tomcat8-jdbc-8.0.37.jar       tomcat8-tribes.jar
java_defaults.mk        tomcat8-catalina-ha-8.0.37.jar      tomcat8-i18n-es-8.0.37.jar               tomcat8-jdbc.jar              tomcat8-util-8.0.37.jar
javaee-api-7.0.jar      tomcat8-catalina-ha.jar             tomcat8-i18n-es.jar                      tomcat8-jni-8.0.37.jar        tomcat8-util.jar
```

I`ve add el-api, el-impl and jsp-api to /usr/share/java due to errors that these libraries couldn't be found in /usr/share/java.

POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.company.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <springframework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.jawr</groupId>
            <artifactId>jawr</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-unit-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/documentation/package/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/documentation/conf</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prod-resources</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>**/*.jks</exclude>
                                        <exclude>**/*.xlsx</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>documentation/package/resources</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/application.properties</filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Duser.timezone=UTC -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US</argLine>
                    <threadCount>1</threadCount>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*IntegrationalTests.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <user.timezone>Etc/UTC</user.timezone>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <!-- <forkCount>3</forkCount> <reuseForks>true</reuseForks> -->

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/jsp</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/jsp</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/tags</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/tags</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                        <version>5.0.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                    <check/>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                    <check/>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

However, I still have problem with finding `com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl`

Comment: I've got a pretty similar exception using Spring 4.3 with embedded Tomcat and Hibernate Validator 5.3

Comment: Was a solution ever found to this problem?

Answer (score 9):

remove

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

For this jar have `javax.el.ExpressionFactory`

and `tomcat8-el-api.jar` have the same one.

This will cause conflict

Answer (score 7):

remove this

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and try with

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
          <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the already answered solutions but none of them work for me on `Spring Boot 2.1.3` **embedded** `tomcat`. Below dependencies worked for me

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem I had one legacy installation on Tomcat7+JDK1.8 box where a new webapp was deployed. It was meant to be run on Tomcat9+JDK10 but this box was an exception.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.ELException: Provider com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found
```

I could not update T7+JDK1.8 so instead made this brute-force change.

```
 rename: tomcat/lib/el-api.jar to el-api.jar_original2.x
 add: tomcat/lib/el-api.jar  version 3.x
 add: tomcat/lib/el-impl-2.2.1-b05.jar   version 2.2.x
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.el/javax.el-api/3.0.1-b06
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.web/el-impl/2.2.1-b05

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot 2.6.15 embedded tomcat worked tomcat-embed-jasper provided dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```