# Getting datasource from tomcat context.xml instead of application.properties

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, tomcat

I have a question about deploying a springboot app. Is it possible to get the data source settings from tomcat context.xml resources instead of the application.properties file?

In this project, I already have a war deployed in tomcat and it uses the data source properties from context .xml of tomcat (it is maven project it and it uses hibernate to access the database).

I'd like to do the same thing but using springboot.

Comment: do you want to create a war file from your spring boot application or are you planning to use the embedded tomcat? if you are planning to create a war file then you should use the same config as you use now.

Comment: yes i wanna create a war file so that it could get the datasource from the context xml of tomcat server , m just adding like a new module of an existing application

Comment: pls refer this link : https://www.journaldev.com/2597/spring-datasource-jndi-with-tomcat-example

Comment: i need the configuration linked to spring data not normal JDBC :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jndi name as you use now like this in spring boot:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb
```

that part is the actual name

```
jdbc/mydb
```

Comment: o i should add some a ressource or jndi  like this in tomcat context xml 

<Resource name="jdbc/mydb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="javauser" password="javadude" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>

and in application . properties i'll add the following properties : 
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb
 is that it ?

Comment: then you should use spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/TestDB in your application.properties

Comment: Yes that is true

Comment: exception : 2018-04-02 12:07:46.681  WARN 1440 --- [ost-startStop-1] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager

Comment: what do you think ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841464/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-el-elmanager